# Realizar update de fechas posteriores y anteriores

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada TABLE_ENTREGAS con 4 campos

```
id
fecha_entrega
fecha_preparacion
fecha_facturacion
```

Donde `fecha_entrega` es un dato ya insertado lo llamo con una variable `$fecha_entrega` esta contiene un dato en formato `datetime: 2017-07-03 12:38:35`

ahora bien

- `fecha_preparacion` debe insertar 4 días anteriores a la `$fecha_entrega`
- `fecha_facturacion` debe insertar 4 días después a la `$fecha_entrega`

Este update es el que tengo para `fecha_preparacion`

```
    tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_ENTREGAS . " set fecha_preparacion = '" . date_sub($fecha_entrega,INTERVAL 4 DAY) . "' where entregas_id = '" . (int)$entregas_id . "'");
```

Este es de 4 días menos pero el update me da el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '4' (T_LNUMBER)

1- No sé cual es el error

2- No sé si agregándole un + ó - al 4 para definir 4 días antes o 4 días después

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás mezclando código PHP con código SQL.

La función [`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) es una instrucción SQL, no PHP, por lo que debe estar dentro de la cadena SQL que estás montando.

Una forma correcta de hacerlo sería:

```
tep_db_query("
  UPDATE " . TABLE_ENTREGAS . "
  SET fecha_preparacion = DATE_SUB('" . tep_db_input($fecha_entrega) . "', INTERVAL 4 DAY)
  WHERE entregas_id = '" . tep_db_input($entregas_id) . "'
");
```

Además, te debo recordar que debes hacer uso de la función [`tep_db_input`](http://phpcrossref.com/xref/oscommerce/includes/functions/database.php.html#l129) para escapar los caracteres SQL que pudieran contener las cadenas.

Por un lado evitarás que el SQL se rompa en ese caso y, además, evitarás que tu código sea vulnerable a inyección SQL (la función `tep_db_input` usa internamente [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://es.php.net/mysqli-real-escape-string)).

---

En cuanto a la consulta de usar + y - sólo debes consultar la documentación de [`DATA_ADD` / `DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) para resolver tu duda:

> **expr** is a string; it may start with a - for negative intervals.

En castellano:

> **expr** es una cadena; podría empezar con un - para intervalos negativos.